# how do I import all the classes in a jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file named protocol.jar and I want to import all the class in the jar file. My OS is Ubuntu and there is no GUI on it.

I had known how to set jar path.

```
javac -cp ".;/home/ubuntu/workspace/protocol/protocol.jar;" MyJavaFile.java
```

Comment: You can import all classes in a _package_ with import "some.package.*" Nothing for all classes in a jar.  What is the real question? Why do you want to import all classes in the jar?

Comment: You don't. You import all the packages in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can import a single class of a package by

`java.io.BufferedReader;`

While if you want to import all classes of a package you can do by

`java.io.*;`

Read it here the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).